# How to design and calculate cost of cloud infrastructure?

Tags: android, resources, cloud, infrastructure

I work on a multiplayer `Android` application, which needs a server too. I would like to use on it my own `NodeJS` based solutions and some databases and would like to separate some storage space for user file storage. I am wondering how to calculate, predict necessary resources. Which parameters should I use for these calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do capacity planning and it's a repetitive process, check out this [link](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/5-steps-for-effective-cloud-capacity-planning-to-avoid-extra-spending/)

Comment: Aren't there any independent cost calculator?